# Dynamic UITableView not scrolling

Tags: uitableview, dynamic, scroll, reloaddata

I have looked through a few posts on this but none really solve the issues I'm having.

Quite a few suggest:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

However, this doesn't enable me to scroll.

The cells are updated dynamically so reloadData is called a few times throughout the "test" I am doing. Once finished the cells are created based on the length of an Array and at the moment they go off the bottom of the screen. I was hoping scrolling would be automatic but no such luck.

If some code would be useful just let me know and any advice would be great

Thanks

Comment: Please post any relevant sample code.

Comment: are you able to use the table otherwise? aka: select items from within the table.